# Error missing identifier oracle in FROM at line 13

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("contabilidad",
    XMLAGG (
        XMLELEMENT ("empleado",
        XMLATTRIBUTES (num_emp AS "id", fecha_alta AS "fecha"),
        XMLELEMENT ("nombre", nombre),
        XMLELEMENT ("nombre",
            (SELECT (grado)
            FROM grado
            WHERE empleado.salario >=grado.salario_min and empleado.salario <=grado.salario_max)
            )
        )
        )
    FROM empleado
    WHERE empleado.num_dep=departamento.num_depto
    )

FROM departamento
WHERE num_depto='CONTABILIDAD'
```

It says there is an error at line 13. It says:

```
Error en la línea de comandos : 13 Columna : 5

Error SQL: ORA-00931: falta el identificador

00931. 00000 -  "missing identifier"
```

I don't understand what it means. Please, help.

Edit: I also tried this:

```
SELECT XMLELEMENT("contabilidad",
    XMLAGG (
        XMLELEMENT ("empleado",
        XMLATTRIBUTES (num_emp AS "id", fecha_alta AS "fecha"),
        XMLELEMENT ("nombre", nombre),
        XMLELEMENT ("grado_salarial",
            (SELECT (grado)
            FROM grado
            WHERE empleado.salario >=grado.salario_min and empleado.salario <=grado.salario_max)
            )
        )
        ))
    FROM empleado
    WHERE empleado.num_dep=departamento.num_depto
AND departamento.nombre='CONTABILIDAD'
```

It says it doesn't recognize 'departamento.nombre'

Comment: I think the parens don't balance.  If you line them up so the closing paren is on a separate line aligned with the opening paren, you can see for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

seems you missed  a table .. try add  a join for departamento

```
    SELECT XMLELEMENT("contabilidad",
        XMLAGG (
            XMLELEMENT ("empleado",
            XMLATTRIBUTES (empleado.num_emp AS "id", empleado.fecha_alta AS "fecha"),
            XMLELEMENT ("nombre", empleado.nombre),
            XMLELEMENT ("grado_salarial",
                (SELECT (grado.grado)
                FROM grado
                WHERE empleado.salario >=grado.salario_min and empleado.salario <=grado.salario_max)
                )
            )
            ))
        FROM empleado
        INNER JOIN departamento ON empleado.num_dep=departamento.num_depto
    AND departamento.nombre='CONTABILIDAD'
```

Comment: I tried this and now it says ```Error en la línea de comandos : 6 Columna : 35
Informe de error -
Error SQL: ORA-00918: columna definida de forma ambigua
00918. 00000 -  "column ambiguously defined"```

Comment: answer updated  with full qualifed  column name  ..  hope the table name right corresponding